# Event Listeners and Global Variables that are defined = "Uncaught TypeError is not a function" when set as function before invoking

Tags: global-variables, typeerror, addeventlistener, v8, function-handle

I ran into an interesting issue when defining a global variable (as null in this case), and having a function change that global variable to a callback that was passed to that function---then trying to invoke the global variable (which is now the function) from a click event listener. However if that global variable wasn't defined (`var globalCallback;` as opposed to `var globalCallback = null;`) then everything is okay. I was under the assumption that the updated variable reference is always accessible by event listeners regardless of the variable's initial value---this doesn't seem to be the case.

See code below:

**TypeError**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    //...

    theSettingFunction(function(){
        //...
    });

    var globalCallback = null; //creates TypeError when invoked after assigned to function
    //var globalCallback = function(){}; //tried this too to test

    function theSettingFunction(callback)
    {
        //...
        globalCallback = callback;
        //...
    }

    /* This event listener doesn't need removing it's a core UI element
       This event gets triggered only after theSettingFunction() has been invoked first */
    document.querySelector('#myButtonDiv').addEventListener('click', function(){
        //...
        globalCallback(); //invoking sees globalCallback as null still = TypeError
    });

    //...

});
```

**Everything Okay**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    //...

    theSettingFunction(function(){
        //...
    });

    var globalCallback;

    function theSettingFunction(callback)
    {
        //...
        globalCallback = callback;
        //...
    }

    /* This event listener doesn't need removing it's a core UI element
       This event gets triggered only after theSettingFunction() has been invoked first */
    document.querySelector('#myButtonDiv').addEventListener('click', function(){
        //...
        globalCallback(); //invoking... hey I see you---you're a function! Invoked.
    });

    //...

});
```

Is this because of the way the JS engine optimizes? Why else are event listeners not getting the updated references to global variables when they're defined?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an engine optimization. It's an effect of JavaScript's funny hoisting rules, and the order in which the various things appear in your code.

The JavaScript language specifies that certain declarations are "hoisted" to the beginning of the program. I guess the idea was to make programming easier by not forcing programmers to pay attention to the order of things -- except, as it turns out, automatic reordering only gets you so far...

For example, you can call a function before defining it. Let's look at an example:

```
func();  // No error, because "func" is defined later.
variable = 1;  // No error, because "variable" is declared later.
function func() {}
var variable;
console.log(variable);  // Will print "1".
```

Under the hood, this is implemented by the engine reordering things as follows:

```
function func() {}
var variable;
func();
variable = 1;
console.log(variable);  // Will print "1".
```

(Again, this is not an optimization, it's a requirement of the JavaScript language.)
An additional detail is that a combined declaration+initialization of a variable is split into two steps, and only the declaration is hoisted. So this:

```
console.log(variable);  // Prints "undefined".
var variable = 1;
```

after internal re-ordering becomes this:

```
var variable;
console.log(variable);  // Prints "undefined".
variable = 1;
```

Now, if we simplify your code a bit, we can see that this is exactly what happens. By inlining `theSettingFunction`, and assuming that the body of the onclick-handler is invoked directly, we get:

```
// This is what `theSettingFunction` does:
globalCallback = function() { /*...*/ }

var globalCallback = null;

// This is what the click-handler does:
globalCallback();
```

which the engine is required to reorder to:

```
var globalCallback;  // hoisted declaration
globalCallback = function() { /*...*/ }
globalCallback = null;
globalCallback();  // TypeError, of course!
```

So you can easily fix the problem by moving the declaration+initialization of `globalCallback` before its first assignment, i.e. the call site of `theSettingFunction`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

    var globalCallback = null;  // Declare and initialize...

    //...

    theSettingFunction(function(){  // ...before assigning.
        //...
    });

    function theSettingFunction(callback)
    {
        //...
        globalCallback = callback;
        //...
    }

    document.querySelector('#myButtonDiv').addEventListener('click', function(){
        //...
        globalCallback();
    });

    //...

});
```

Arguably, this will also make your code easier to read, because it's easier for humans to understand in which order things are happening when they don't have to take any invisible reordering into account. For this reason, personally, I would also move the definition of `theSettingFunction` before its first call.